# How to expand the rect mark point of the Apache Echarts to the bar full width?

Tags: apache-echarts

I need to mark historical value on the bar chart, but I cannot find a way how to size the mark point to cover the bar in width.

So I need something like this:

[image]

Here is my current option mock [codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/exciting-chatterjee-3p5938](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/exciting-chatterjee-3p5938)